# jQuery working in console.log but not in variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this `console.log()`

```
console.log($($('.biggie img:visible')[0]).attr('src').split('/').pop());
```

This returns:

```
4.jpg
```

When i put the line into a variable like this:

```
var jpg = $($('.biggie img:visible')[0]).attr('src').split('/').pop();
```

The console says:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'split' of undefined
```

What is going on?

Thank you!!

Edit:

Sorry, sorry, I know what is going on now, you pointed me all into the right direction below my answer...here is the whole code:

```
imgVis.fadeOut(400, function() {
                var jpg = $($('.biggie img:visible')[0]).attr('src').split('/').pop(),
                    nr = parseInt(jpg,10);
                $(this).next(':hidden').fadeIn(400);
                console.log($($('.biggie img:visible')[0]).attr('src').split('/').pop());
});
```

I actually had no image visible. Ashaming. :/ Thank you!!!

Comment: did you mean `var s = $($('.biggie img:visible')[0]).attr('src').split('/').pop(); console.log(s)`

Comment: This the image is not loaded properly.  check for image status

Comment: call this within $(document).load(function(){}

Comment: @user1671639 It is, I can see it, and still then the console.log() would not work!?!

Comment: @user1671639 and C-Link: You were all right...see my updated question. :)

Comment: @dollarvar Glad to help, so it is better to close this question :)

Comment: @user1671639 How? I cannot delete it anymore because there is an answer!?! Edit: I flagged it. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Hm ... this is really strange. Are these two lines one after each other. If not, then I'll suggest that your selector is not matching what you expect or there is no `src` attribute of the matched elements. I'll suggest two things:

1) Replace this

```
$($('.biggie img:visible')[0])
```

with just

```
$('.biggie img:visible')
```

What you are doing there is to convert the jQuery element to a DOM element and the again make it jQuery element.

2) `console.log($('.biggie img:visible').length);`

If the length is `0`, then there are still no visible images.

Comment: Thanks Krasimir, I solved the question (the others did). See my updated question. ;)